# Batch file to copy file, if file exists rename file with timestamp

Tags: windows, batch-file, cmd, file-rename

I have a batch file which copies a file from the network to local, and if the file exists, adds a timestamp. Actually I'm renaming the file first and then copying the file.

```
Echo Off
REN "C:\Project\3d_Model.dgn" "* %Date:/=% %Time::=.%.dgn"
xcopy /Y /S /i "Z:\Project\3d_Model.dgn" "C:\Project\"
```

The problem I have is the date is added after the file extension and looks like this:

```
3d_Model.dgn Sat 07122019  9.05.46.36.dgn
```

How can I remove the file extension and then rename the file?

Comment: If the answer provided doesn't suit your real purpose, either a `Call`, a `For` loop or `forfiles.exe` may help. Use the Command Prompt window to enter each command followed by `/?` to read their usage information.

Comment: You wanted to remove the file extension but you have showed that in your example.

Answer (score 1):

How about

```
REN "C:\Project\3d_Model.dgn" "3d_Model%Date:/=% %Time::=.%.dgn"
```

Answer (score 0):

Use a [`for` loop](https://ss64.com/nt/for.html) to split the original file name, using the [`~`-modifiers](https://ss64.com/nt/syntax-args.html) of its meta-variable:

```cmd
for %%I in ("C:\Project\3d_Model.dgn") do ren "%%~I" "%%~nI %DATE:/=% %TIME::=.%%%~xI"
```

To do this directly in a Command Prompt window, it looks like this:

```cmd
for %I in ("C:\Project\3d_Model.dgn") do ren "%~I" "%~nI %DATE:/=% %TIME::=.%%~xI"
```

*N. B.:*
Regard that `%DATE%` and `%TIME%` return region-dependent values!

Answer (score 0):

why not working `%time%` in

`for %I in ("C:\Project\3d_Model.dgn") do ren "%~I" "%~nI %DATE:/=% %TIME::=.%%~xI"`